# Creating a pagination function in PHP that exist in other class that generate the HTML

Tags: php, html

I need help creating a pagination function in PHP. I have created one that works great if it exist in the index page. I tried to put it in an PHP class it didn't work. Any help please. This is the code:

```
function paging($eu,$limit,$back,$next,$nume,$t1)
  {
   $l=1;
   $i=0;

   echo $eu;  //$
   echo $limit; // maximum record per page
   //echo $back;
   echo $next; //next page 
   echo $nume; // number of rows

   if($back >=0)
    {
    $a = "<a _href='index?start=$back'>PREV</a>";
   }
   else
   {
    $a ="";
   }

   for($i=0;$i < $nume;$i=$i+$limit)
   {
    if($i <> $eu)
     {
      $b = " <='index?start=$i'>$l</a>";
      $c = "";
     }
    else 
     { 
      $b = "";
      $c =$l; 
      $l=$l+1;
     }
   }

   if($t1 < $nume) 
   {
    $e = "<='index.php?start=$next'>NEXT</a>";
   }


   $pg = "
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td>$a</td>
     <td>$b $c</td>
     <td>$e</td>
    </tr>
   </table> 
   ";

   return $pg; 

  }
```

Comment: what does it "didn't work" mean?

Comment: its not posting back the html code to my index page. its only giving me prev next and the page that its in

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is where you're messing up:

```
for($i=0;$i < $nume;$i=$i+$limit) {
   if ($i <> $eu) {
       $b = " <='index?start=$i'>$l</a>";  // <--- here
       $c = "";
   } else { 
       $b = ""; // <<--- here
       $c =$l; 
       $l=$l+1;
   }
}
```

You're overwriting the `$b` value on each loop iteration, instead of appending the "current" page HTML. Most likely you'd want something like this instead:

```
       $b .= " <='index?start=$i'>$l</a>";
          ^--- concatenation operator
```

which is the same as doing:

```
       $b = $b . " <='index?start=$i'>$l</a>";
```

Comment: hey thanks for your help i tried it but it didnt work 
your right about the location of the problem .. but i cant find the solution